# How to unit test with method return void and haven't parameters?

Tags: android, testing

I'm beginner android developer. I'm learning unit test in android and I have problem with method return void or hasn't parameters.
How to test its?

And do you know library about unit test on android? can you tell me, please! :3

Thank so much!

Comment: some helpful resources http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html
https://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-basic-testing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#testing):

"There are two recommended ways of setting up testing on code and resources in a library project:

- You can set up a test project that instruments an application project that depends on the library project. You can then add tests to the project for library-specific features.
- You can set up a standard application project that depends on the library and put the instrumentation in that project. This lets you create a self-contained project that contains both the tests/instrumentations and the code to test."